# What is the difference b/w PHP null value and Mysql database field null value

Tags: php, mysql

I encountered a problem while fetching database field value which is basically a null value

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field=''; //this means null in php
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IS NULL; //this means null in mysql db
```

Both queries are producing different result.

What is the difference b/w both null values and how can be the null values different?

Comment: The *correct* way to test for null in SQL is `x IS NULL` or `x IS NOT NULL`. This is just how it's defined. `x = NULL` should return false (for *any* `x`) per SQL standard, but has been broken in some SQL implementations. These semantics are useful for joins. Sadly, I don't have an answer of how to turn "passing a null" into `IS NULL` magically -- but this is trivial with prepared statements (oh, you *are* using those, no?) and a condition to select "which" query. However, I have not run into a case where I've needed to support NULL as such and am tempted to argue a [blank] not-NULL field.

Comment: Technically '' in PHP is an *empty string* it will evaluate to a boolean false, hence `null == ''` but only because the `==` operator does type casting. `null === ''` is `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When querying the database, definitions from PHP are thrown out the window. In SQL, "" represents an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP programming, the difference between null, zero, false, and empty string easily becomes ambiguous because of PHP's == vs. ===. Oracle, MSSQL, and MySql (sometimes?) are a lot more strict in this respect.

PHP, as a high-level language, allows loose comparisons, as described by [PHP type comparison tables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: This is exactly correct. Using `==`, an empty string and `null` are equivalent. But they are indeed different values in PHP, and you can tell them apart using `===`, `is_string()`, and `is_null()`.